# Cannot save an object in the state with its keys in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, state

These are the functions that I use for my class component

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        data: []
    }
}

async componentDidMount() {
    var citas_data = await makeRequest('api/products/');
    citas_data.data.map(data => (
        this.setState({
            data: [...this.state.data, [{ id: data._id, name: data.name }]]
        })
    ))

}
```

This is the information contained in the var *citas_data*, brings it from an api I have in nodejs.

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "_id": "600db7499f933921c0a56f95",
        "name": "laptop hp 8gb",
        "category": "razer",
        "price": 80000,
        "imgUrl": "https://cnet1.cbsistatic.com/img/P2IudsL7buTCG7zvs4gq5BNpOS4=/470x376/2018/06/27/ba86ad23-6537-4466-b709-e3eaeb662700/11-asus-tuf-gaming-fx504.jpg",
        "createdAt": "2021-01-24T18:07:05.811Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-01-24T18:07:22.941Z"
    },
    {
        "_id": "600e39f22ac1a14a10c8ed59",
        "name": "laptopa razer",
        "category": "raazer",
        "price": 99000,
        "imgUrl": "https://cnet1.cbsistatic.com/img/P2IudsL7buTCG7zvs4gq5BNpOS4=/470x376/2018/06/27/ba86ad23-6537-4466-b709-e3eaeb662700/11-asus-tuf-gaming-fx504.jpg",
        "createdAt": "2021-01-25T03:24:34.776Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-01-25T03:24:34.776Z"
    },
    {
        "_id": "600e3d607e0b6b44d8e98bf8",
        "name": "laptopa razer",
        "category": "raazer",
        "price": 99000,
        "imgUrl": "https://cnet1.cbsistatic.com/img/P2IudsL7buTCG7zvs4gq5BNpOS4=/470x376/2018/06/27/ba86ad23-6537-4466-b709-e3eaeb662700/11-asus-tuf-gaming-fx504.jpg",
        "createdAt": "2021-01-25T03:39:12.093Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-01-25T03:39:12.093Z"
    }
],
"status": 200,
"statusText": "OK",
```

And when executing the code I get these errors **Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, name}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.**

```
   11 | 
   12 |    async componentDidMount() {
   13 |        var citas_data = await makeRequest('api/products/');
 > 14 |        citas_data.data.map(data => (
   15 |            this.setState({
   16 |                data: [...this.state.data, [{ id: data._id, name: data.name },]]
   17 |            })
```

Comment: Doing setState inside a map function should be avoided as setState is asynchronous. Would be nice if you can provide some data for which you are trying to do a setState

Comment: Maybe create an array to fill it with push in the map function. Then, after the map function, update the state. var data = {}; ...map(d => { data.push({id=d.id,...})}). And this setState(...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to change the name of the state "data" to a different one.

---

Example:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        data: []
    }
}
```

To:

```
 constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        dates: []
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**try to do that**
 async componentDidMount() {
   const results=[]
   const citas_data = await makeRequest('api/products/'); 
       
   citas_data.forEach(item => {
   results.push({
     id: data._id,
     name: data.name 
    });
   });
this.setState({data:results});
```